# Getting SIGILL in float to fixed conversion

Tags: c++, arm, porting

I'm receiving a SIGILL after running the following code. I can't really figure what's wrong with it.

The target platform is ARM, and I'm trying to port a known library (in which this code is contained)

```
void convertFloatToFixed(float nX, float nY, unsigned int &nFixed) {
    short sx = (short) (nX * 32);
    short sy = (short) (nY * 32);

    unsigned short *ux = (unsigned short*) &sx;
    unsigned short *uy = (unsigned short*) &sy;

    nFixed = (*ux << 16) | *uy;
}
```

Any help on it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In C++, prefer named casts like `static_cast` for your first cast, and `reinterpret_cast` for your second, such as: `short sx = static_cast<short>(nX * 32);` and `unsigned short ux = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short&>(sx);`

Comment: I've pinpointed the cause of the SIGILL to the last line but can't understand why. Is there anything wrong in there?

Comment: I'm guessing at bad code generation, blowing the return address on the stack.  The code provides plenty of rope to allow the compiler to hang itself.  Start by getting rid of the pointer casts, a simple cast will do.

Comment: Actually the SIGILL is being thrown when I try to access the `sx` and `sy` variables, so I'm guessing something wrong in the float to integer conversion.

Comment: Are you 'pinpointing' this by commenting out code? If so, when you comment out the last line, the compiler (if optimizing) will throw away the entire function body. Can you disassemble the function, and show exactly which instruction (and registers at the time) is causing the fault? It should then be extremely obvious what's going wrong. Also, which ARM SoC is this? You could have a buggy one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ARM processors have hardware floating-point, and some don't, so it's possible that this function is being compiled for hardware floating-point but your platform lacks a floating-point unit, so the floating-point instructions cause the processor to report an illegal instruction. If this is the first floating-point computation in your test program, that's extremely likely to be the problem. Check your platform's documentation to find which -march option you need to pass to gcc, or look at the compilation options used by some program that already works.

This function does not have defined behaviour, and without an indication of what the desired behaviour is it's hard to suggest an improvement. Try something like this for a start:-

```
void convertFloatToFixed(float nX, float nY, unsigned int &nFixed) {
    assert(nX * 32 < INT_MAX);
    assert(nY * 32 < INT_MAX);

    int sx = nX * 32;
    int sy = nY * 32;

    unsigned int ux = sx;
    unsigned int uy = sy;

    nFixed = (ux << 16) | uy;
}
```

I've got rid of the pointer casts, which (as others have pointed out) break the strict aliasing rule. I've also used `int` instead of `short`. There's generally no point having `short` auto variables, since they're widened to `int`s before computations anyway. (It's a good job they are, as shifting a `short` by 16 bits would not be very useful.) I've added some checks so your debug builds can find out if the float-to-integer conversion will overflow, which causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: I will accept your answer in the basis that the problem as related with the lack of a floating-point unit on the system I was testing with at the time (almost 2 years ago)